# How can I display elements even if their parents v-if directive does not match?

Tags: vuejs2

I got an object. The template iterates over this. I want to tell Vue: if there is a "link" property in that object, then wrap the following elements with an a tag else show it anyway.

I tried it with slots. It doesn't work, not possible to open a HTML element and close it in various scopes.

An ugly way is commented in the template section. Is it possible to avoid the redundancy?

So, my object

```
data() {
    return {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'item with link',
                link: '#'
            },
            {
               text: 'item without link',
                // no link prop !!!
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

The template:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
            <a v-if="item.link" :href="item.link">
                <!-- how to display this <p> with or without the parent -->
                <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
            </a>
            <!-- one possibility is to set a negation to <p> again, but its not nice -->
            <p v-if="!item.link">{{ item.text }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

the result should be

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">
            <p>item with link</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>item without link</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is very little redundancy. You could replace `v-if="!item.link"` by `v-else` though. Also you should not try to do stuff like `<template><a></template>` and it will likely not work, because its agains the XML spec. You have to close elements correctly, in contradiction with how you could solve such issues with languages like PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use v-else as below?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
            <a v-if="item.link" :href="item.link">
                <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
            </a>
            <p v-else>{{ item.text }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This will not avoid the redundancy.